# django mezzanine multiple blogs on same site

Tags: python, django, mezzanine, django-apps

I'm using Mezzanine for my blog and I want to add another page similar to the blog but separate in design and structure. Is this possible to do within 1 mezzanine project?

Comment: This is definitely possible, though I haven't done it myself. The typical approach is to use separate "Blog Categories" and create separate pages for listing each one.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.. I tried something similar where I created a category that will be used only for this new page (newpage).. I can than see the posts for this category on (blog/category/newpage..) but the problem is that I don't want the posts of newpage category be seen in the normal blog_post_list.html. Also I did not understand how to than style differently this page and the blog_post_detail.html posts under this category.. if you have any hints let me know ;)

Comment: I suspect that you want to stop using the default category altogether. A lot of people want their different blogs combined in one central feed and I'm guessing there's no way to change that on the default category.

Comment: I don't think there's a real clean way to have multiple list views at the moment. I would search the mailing list, there are a few approaches mentioned there.

Comment: @Torostar Have you had any luck with this? I am having the exact same problem.